# Select current link in menu

Tags: javascript

I'm using MentisMenu for my site, and I'm trying to get the active menu selection to be set to active. I can get the Menu and submenus to activate and expand, but the actual link selected will not be marked active. Anyone?

```
      const currentLinkParents = currentLink => {
                let target = currentLink
                let parent = []
                while (target) {
                    // Get only nav-link
                    if (target.classList.contains('nav-item')) parent.unshift(target.querySelector('.nav-link'))
                    // Stop on treeview
                    if (target.classList.contains('treeview')) break
                    target = target.parentNode
                }
                return parent
            }
            const updateMenu = currentLink => {
                document.querySelectorAll('#menu .active').forEach(i => i.classList.remove('active', 'show'))

                for (const i of currentLinkParents(currentLink)) {
                    i.classList.add('active')
                    i.classList.contains('treeview-toggle') && i.classList.add('show')
                }
            }
            updateMenu(document.querySelector(`#menu a[href="${window.location.pathname.split('/').pop()}"]`))
```

Sample HTML here:

```
      <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link has-icon treeview-toggle" href="#"><i class="material-icons">construction</i>Engineering</a>
          <ul class="nav">
               <li><a href="renovations_active.aspx" class="nav-link">Active Renovations</a></li>
                <li><a href="maintenance_requests.aspx" class="nav-link">Maintenance Requests</a></li>
                 <li><a href="projects.aspx" class="nav-link">Projects</a></li>
                 <li><a href="unit_recurring_events.aspx" class="nav-link">Recurring Events</a></li>
    
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav-link treeview-toggle">Inventories</a>
                       <ul class="nav">
                         <li><a href="inventory_management.aspx" class="nav-link">Stock Inventory</a></li>
                          <li><a href="key_inventory.aspx" class="nav-link">Master Keys</a></li>
                             </ul>
                               </li>
                                 </ul>
                                 </li>
```

In this example, if I select "Master Keys" then the menus Engineering and Inventories both expand and are set to active, but the Master Keys selection is not marked active.

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the following line after the call to updateMenu() fixes it:

document.querySelector(`#menu a[href="${window.location.pathname.split('/').pop()}"]`).classList.add('active');